# Adding DIV dynamically from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tree, element

I am trying to build a Tree Chart dynamically based on a `JSON` file.

The basic code goes like this :

```
var arrayFinalChartData = [{
    "1": "2",
        "id": "4d344e35-d8b1-49ec-c564-759639816704",
        "parentid": "rootDiv"
}, {
    "3": "4",
        "id": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f",
        "parentid": "rootDiv"
}, {
    "OS": "WINDOW",
        "id": "15d332c3-613d-4aee-8d17-b731c682f242",
        "parentid": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f"
}];


$('#loadChart').click(function () {
    //console.log("arrayFinalChartData:" + (JSON.stringify(arrayFinalChartData));
    // build chart

    $(arrayFinalChartData).each(function (i, obj) {

        //console.log(arrayFinalChartData[i].id);
        //console.log(arrayFinalChartData[i].parentid);


        //Retrieve the innerHTML

        itemStringDetails = JSON.stringify(obj);
        var mySubString = "";

        for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {

            var partString = itemStringDetails.split(',')[n];

            console.log("partString :" + partString);

            if ((partString.indexOf('id', 0) == -1) && (partString.indexOf('parentid', 0) == -1)) {

                var mySubString = partString;
                console.log("mySubString :" + mySubString);
            };


        };


        itemHTML = mySubString.replace("{", '');

        console.log("itemHTML:" + itemHTML);  



            $('#buildTree').append('div').addClass("newDIV").attr('id', arrayFinalChartData[i].id).html(itemHTML).data("parentid", arrayFinalChartData[i].parentid);


        //console.log(this.parentid);
    });
});
```

---

The full HTML and JS available at: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/komuh/3/edit)

**Note:** Each `div` has an `ID` and `ParentID`. The hierarchy to follow the `ParentID`.

All Div's must retain the Attributes as in JSON so that when we save, we get the same Json.Please note that "1":"2"..."5":"6" happen to be the innerHTML of the respective Div. The content could be - "OS":"window". "version":"XP" etc...It will be a Chart of the network devices

Comment: What is "1" : "2"? Why not use identical field for all objects? For example { idnwhatisit: [1, 2], ... Where this variable is coming from? How many levels of hierarchy are there: limited or unknown?

Comment: what should the generated html look like

Comment: Thanks. Edited. How can we add all 3 DIVs to their respective Parent ?

Comment: @Ivan Ivanov
"1":"2" OR "OS":"Window" etc... would be the innerHTML of the newly generated DIv.
The levels would depend on the supplied JSON where each DIV will have ID, innerHTML and Parentid.

Comment: @Arun
The HTML would look like an Organisational chart. The chart would grow deeper in level based on the json where each Div will be defined by ID,ParentID and innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
if (arrayFinalChartData[i].parentid == "rootDiv")
    $("#buildTree").append("<div id='" + arrayFinalChartData[i].id + "'>It's here</div>");
else
    $("#" + arrayFinalChartData[i].parentid)
    .append("<div id='" + arrayFinalChartData[i].id + "'>It's here</div>")
```

Comment: We need to add all new DIV's to <div id="buildTree"> wgich is part of the HTML. We will also pick up the innerHTML of each new Div from the Json("1":"2"...etc ) with a variable called "itemHTML".

Comment: Do you want the `div`s in JSON with `parentid` as `rootDiv` to be added in the `#buildTree`?

Comment: Yes. And Div with "id": "15d332c3-613d-4aee-8d17-b731c682f242" will be the child of Div with id: "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f"

Comment: Then my code does exactly what you need, doesn't it?

Comment: I guess we need to take a generic Parent-Child based approach while building the Tree. The code is just a sample. It could go to any level. All DIV's would have ID, innerHTML and ParentID. Div's with ParentID "rootDiv" would be the Level 1 ( rootDiV being the root or level 0 ) . All of them need to have the attributes as defined in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tree"></div>
<script>
    'use strict';

    var data = [{
        "1": "2",
            "id": "4d344e35-d8b1-49ec-c564-759639816704",
            "parentid": "rootDiv"
    }, {
        "3": "4",
            "id": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f",
            "parentid": "rootDiv"
    }, {
        "5": "6",
            "id": "15d332c3-613d-4aee-8d17-b731c682f242",
            "parentid": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f"
    }],
    root = $(document.getElementById('tree')),
    key,
    tree = {},
    tmp;
    /*
        {
            id1: [array of object woth this parent id],
            id2: ...
        }
    */
    for (key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tmp = data[key];
            if (tree[tmp.parentid] === undefined) {
                tree[tmp.parentid] = [];
            }
            tree[tmp.parentid].push(data[key]);
        }
    }
    console.log(tree);
    //as structure of json is very strange
    function getContent(node) {
        var key;
        for (key in node) {
            return node[key];
        }
    }

    function recBuild(tree, seed) {
        var i, 
            arr = tree[seed],
            len = arr.length,
            //output html is a array of chars. That is the fastest way
            //to concatenate strings
            frag = [];
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //make sequence of divs with current parent id
            frag.push("<div id='" + arr[i].id + "'>" + getContent(arr[i]));
            //if current id is someone's parent id, then make subtree
            if (tree[arr[i].id] !== undefined) {
                frag.push(recBuild(tree, arr[i].id));
            }
            frag.push("</div>");
        }
        //convert array to string
        return frag.join('');
    }

    root.append(recBuild(tree, 'rootDiv'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPD: if want to change margin by level

```
function recBuild(tree, seed, level) {
        var i, 
            arr = tree[seed],
            len = arr.length,
            //output html is a array of chars. That is the fastest way
            //to concatenate strings
            frag = [];
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            //make sequence of divs with current parent id
            frag.push("<div style='margin-left:" + (level*10) + "px' id='" + arr[i].id + "'>" + getContent(arr[i]));
            //if current id is someone's parent id, then make subtree
            if (tree[arr[i].id] !== undefined) {
                frag.push(recBuild(tree, arr[i].id, level + 1));
            }
            frag.push("</div>");
        }
        //convert array to string
        return frag.join('');
    }

    root.append(recBuild(tree, 'rootDiv', 0));
```

Upd2 without jquery

```
'use strict';

var data = [{
    "1": "2",
        "id": "4d344e35-d8b1-49ec-c564-759639816704",
        "parentid": "rootDiv"
}, {
    "3": "4",
        "id": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f",
        "parentid": "rootDiv"
}, {
    "5": "6",
        "id": "15d332c3-613d-4aee-8d17-b731c682f242",
        "parentid": "951de378-b191-498e-b31f-7250e6a7ef1f"
}],
root = document.getElementById('tree'),
key,
tree = {},
tmp;
/*
    {
        id1: [array of object woth this parent id],
        id2: ...
    }
*/
for (key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        tmp = data[key];
        if (tree[tmp.parentid] === undefined) {
            tree[tmp.parentid] = [];
        }
        tree[tmp.parentid].push(data[key]);
    }
}
console.log(tree);
//as structure of json is very strange
function getContent(node) {
    var key;
    for (key in node) {
        return node[key];
    }
}

function recBuild(tree, seed, level) {
    var i, 
        arr = tree[seed],
        len = arr.length,
        //output html is a array of chars. That is the fastest way
        //to concatenate strings
        frag = [];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //make sequence of divs with current parent id
        frag.push("<div style='margin-left:" + (level*10) + "px' id='" + arr[i].id + "'>" + getContent(arr[i]));
        //if current id is someone's parent id, then make subtree
        if (tree[arr[i].id] !== undefined) {
            frag.push(recBuild(tree, arr[i].id, level + 1));
        }
        frag.push("</div>");
    }
    //convert array to string
    return frag.join('');
}

root.innerHTML = (recBuild(tree, 'rootDiv', 0));
```

Recursive solution using jQuery. Ask question further

Comment: The way I see, there should have been 2 siblings( common ParentId)  and then the third one as child of 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, it is. there are two siblings of some div (where id="tree"), and third is subtree of second one.

Comment: Is it possible to stylise the div and put innerHTML ("1":"2"....) to make chart clear ? I mean can we use a Dummy root so that levels become clear ? At this moment 2nd and 3rd Div VISUALLY appear to be the children of 1st Div.
Also need to maintain the attributes of the respective Div as in the JSON ( their ID,innerHTML and ParentID ) so that they be "retrieved" later for saving.

Comment: see UPD, there are levels. Level is passed as incrementing argument to every function call.

Comment: You rightly noticed and I deliberately used "1":"2" that this is not really a "key-value" pair. While ID and ParentID are proper key-value pairs, "1":"2" is just a "content place holder" for "arbitrary content" as innerHTML for the Div's.
The user may have "OS":"WINDOW" or "maxTemp":30.....or similar content. In that sense it's arbitrary and we need to extract that from the json and use as innerHTML of the respective div.

Comment: Is that a question? Please, elaborate

Comment: Not a question. Just tried to explain what I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution: http://fiddle.jshell.net/qZGVk/1/

```
$('#loadChart').click(function () {
  var i = arrayFinalChartData.length;
var counter = 0;
$(arrayFinalChartData).each(function (i, obj) {

    if(obj.parentid === "rootDiv"){
        $('#buildTree').append('<div id="'+obj.id+'" parentid ="'+obj.parentid+'">Parent id:'+obj.parentid+'</div>');
    }
    counter++;
});
 if(counter === i){
 $(arrayFinalChartData).each(function (i, obj) {
if(obj.parentid !== "rootDiv"){

var result = $.grep(arrayFinalChartData, function(e){ return obj.parentid == e.id; });

       if (typeof result !== 'undefined' && result.length > 0) {
            $('#'+result[0].id+'').append('<div id="'+obj.id+'" parentid ="'+obj.parentid+'">Child id:'+obj.id+'</div>');
        }
    else{
        alert("no existing parent");
    }


}

});
      }

});
```

Comment: We need to start the tree with Div's having parentid as "rootDiv". Two divs can not have same id.

Comment: I edit it, you should learn to use the word "attribute" if you want to have parentid, you are really confusing, and for the duplicate you filter the date so there will no duplicate Ids.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.